# How to correctly use Apache Common BeanUtil's BeanComparator to benefit of introspection?

Tags: java, javabeans, apache-commons, introspection, apache-commons-beanutils

I searched around on SOF but don't find a so basic question related to BeanUtil use.

I have a POJO class let's say for example `UserPojo` whose the class code is :

```java
public class UserPojo{

    private String name;
    private int    gender;
    private int    size;

    //Setters
    public void setName(String name) {this.name  =name;}
    public void setGender(int gender){this.gender=gender;}
    public void setSize(int size)    {this.size  =size;}

    //getters
    public String getName()  {return this.name;}
    public int    getGender(){return this.gender;}
    public int    getSize()  {return this.size;}
}
```

My question is, how to use BeanUtil to automatically compare two instance of this bean ?

I tried this :

```java
final BeanComparator<UserPojo> comparator = new BeanComparator<UserPojo>();
final int comparison = comparator.compare(expectedPojo, receivedPojo);
```

But it end on the following error:

```java
java.lang.ClassCastException : UserPojo cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable
```

I understand that my Pojo should implement the standard `Comparable` interface, but this way the comparison do not rely on introspection and the import of BeanUtil seems very useless...

So, how to correctly use it ?

Answer (score 0):

You've gotta look at the various constructors on there:

[BeanComparator(String property)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html#BeanComparator%28java.lang.String%29)

- Constructs a property-based comparator for beans.

[BeanComparator(String property, Comparator comparator)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanComparator.html#BeanComparator%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Comparator%29)

- Constructs a property-based comparator for beans.

Here's the former's javadoc (2nd para is your answer):

> Constructs a property-based comparator for beans. This compares two
>   beans by the property specified in the property parameter. This
>   constructor creates a BeanComparator that uses a ComparableComparator
>   to compare the property values.
>
> Passing "null" to this constructor will cause the BeanComparator to
>   compare objects based on natural order, that is java.lang.Comparable.

As you'd expect, the constructor you're invoking does just this:

```
this(null);
```

For comparing multiple properties, you could make use of the 2nd variant

```
Collections.sort(collection, 
  new BeanComparator("property1", 
    new BeanComparator("property2", 
      new BeanComparator("property3"))));
```

I personally felt that the `Apache Commons CompareToBuilder` and `Google Guava’s ComparisonChain` as better choices.

Comment: Don't know `compareToBuilde` and `comparisonChain` do they allow for automatical bean comprarison ?

Comment: No, but they help you implement the `compareTo` method, just like `EqualsBuilder` helps you build the `equals` method. Not the greatest of benefits I agree, but needing to specify the parameter names (possibly b/c it uses reflection under the hood) in the `BeanComparator` doesn't sit well with me.

Answer (score 0):

I finally gave up and code this.
It do not answer the question but this is my way to tackle this problem :

```
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils;

public static void assertBeansEqual(final Object expected, final Object given) {
    try {
        final Map<String, String> expectedDescription = BeanUtils.describe(expected);
        final Map<String, String> givenDescription = BeanUtils.describe(given);

        // if the two bean don't share the same attributes.
        if (!(expectedDescription.keySet().containsAll(givenDescription.keySet()))) {
            final Set<String> keySet = givenDescription.keySet();
            keySet.removeAll(expectedDescription.keySet());
            fail("The expected bean has not the same attributes than the given bean, the followings fields are not present in the expected bean :" + keySet);
        }
        if (!(givenDescription.keySet().containsAll(expectedDescription.keySet()))) {
            final Set<String> keySet = expectedDescription.keySet();
            keySet.removeAll(givenDescription.keySet());
            fail("The expected bean has not the same attributes than the given bean, the followings fields are not present in the given bean :" + keySet);
        }

        final List<String> differences = new LinkedList<String>();
        for (final String key : expectedDescription.keySet()) {
            if (isNull(expectedDescription.get(key))) {
                // if the bean1 value is null and not the other -> not equal. This test is
                // required to avoid NPE attributes values are null. (null object dot not have
                // equals method).
                if (!isNull(givenDescription.get(key))) {
                    differences.add(key);
                }
            }
            else {
                // if two attributes don't share an attributes value.
                if (!expectedDescription.get(key).equals(givenDescription.get(key))) {
                    differences.add(key);
                }
            }
        }
        if (!differences.isEmpty()) {
            String attributes = "";
            for (final String attr : differences) {
                attributes = attributes + "|" + attr;
            }
            fail("Assertion fail, the expected bean and the given bean attributes values differ for the followings attributes : " + attributes + "|");
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```